# Is there a faster way to get checksum of table with particular condition?

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am currently using this for most of tables for detecting changes in table.

```
CHECKSUM TABLE wp_options
```

and for some other tables like `wp_posts` where many kinds of records are there, so using something like this.

```
select max(post_modified_gmt) from wp_posts where post_type="page"
```

so in second query the problem is its taking too time because table to too large and have lots of records, is there any more efficient way to improve it or is there any faster `checksum` option in mysql for tables with specifying condition.

Comment: is your post_type column is indexed ?

Comment: hmm can you try this on mysql and share the output ? `explain select max(post_modified_gmt) from wp_posts where post_type="page"`

Comment: ohh yes.. it returned one row..
1, select_type=simple,table=wp_posts,type=ref,possible_keys=type_status_date,key=type_status_date,key_len=62,ref=const,rows=79,Extra=using where

Comment: no does not look like the `post_type` is indexed and its not picking it. what you see when you run `show indexes from wp_posts`

Comment: ohh yes, add one index with just one column for post_type, and this index name is now showing in explain

Comment: and hope the query will be faster now for sure... By rule using min() max() the optimizer will look for a where condition on an indexed col